# Compare each cell from column A with each cell from column B and colum C

Tags: excel, vba

I've a Excel file with three columns. Cells in each columns are different ranges for example column A has 797340 cells, column B has 91617 cells and column C has 95891 cells. I need to compare each value in column A and look if this value is on column B or it's in column C and if the condition is TRUE then bold the cell or change the color to red. If there any way to achieve this using Excel formulas? Any help?

Comment: Is the idea of the bold/color change to draw the user's attention to these rows? If so, you can also create a custom filter and use filtering + re-apply to hide the non-matching rows.

Comment: @JAGAnalyst the idea is get some way to know which values from column A are in column B or column C in order to remove them later manually or better clean the cell if is possible with the same conditional formatting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use conditional formating. Kindly refer to below image. Its just a demo.

> Select Column A> Goto Conditional Formatting >> New Rules >> Use Formula to determine which
> cells to format
>
> Enter the formula in  >> Format values where formula
> is true >> select the format >> OK

```
=OR( IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(A1,B:B,2,0)),FALSE,TRUE),IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(A1,C:C,3,0)),FALSE,TRUE))
```

[image]

Comment: this formula will iterate for each value in column A and see if this value exists on column B and column C or just check if values at cells X in column A,B,C are the same? I'm confused

Comment: this formula will iterate for each value in column A and see if this value exists on column B or column C. Just try it.

Comment: so that means if number in column A is on column B or C then formula will be set as TRUE if not then will be FALSE and I need to replicate in order to move in range, right?

Comment: With either of the formulas Santosh or I have posted, you have to apply the formula to all of the cells in column A within the conditional formatting rule itself.

Comment: @santosh see here the result http://www.dropmocks.com/mBr2G6 is that right? I never get TRUE :-(

Comment: Just trim your data and convert the column format to number or general .

Comment: Or in your vlookup  isntead of VLOOKUP(A1,B:B,2,0)  change to VLOOKUP(A1 & "" ,B:B,2,0)

Comment: @Santosh what you mean with **trim**? also I notice something new, for example 4141893270 is the same as +584141893270 or 04141893270 so how to deal with this particularity? Your formula does not work in this case I though. It's possible to remove the first values in order to leave only 10 digits as for example 4141893270?

Comment: sometimes there are spaces in data because of which vlookup does not give correct result. So i just want you to verify there are no leading and trailing spaces to the data.

Comment: @Santosh it's not working for me I change to this `=OR( IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(TRIM(A1),B:B,2,0)),FALSE,TRUE),IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(TRIM(A1),C:C,3,0)),FALSE,TRUE))` and delete first cell because I don't need and see the results http://www.dropmocks.com/mBr5CE, what's wrong?

Comment: Put the formula as >=OR( IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(A1 & "",B:B,2,0)),FALSE,TRUE),IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(A1 & "",C:C,3,0)),FALSE,TRUE))

Comment: Also copy your data from column A to C to notepad then press find and replace option (ctrl + H).In find what would be two blank spaces for that press space bar twice and replace with single blank space for that press space bar once. Press ok and copy the data from notepad and put it back to excel.

Answer (score 0):

To make life easy use conditional formatting and apply your own custom rule.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/quick-start-apply-conditional-formatting-HA010370614.aspx

Comment: Yes this will work for the formatting part but I'm asking for a formula to achieve this ;) anyway thanks

Answer (score 0):

Unless there is a reason you need to handle this with code, you can set conditional formatting within excel based on a formula.

For example, you can create a new conditional formatting rule based on a formula such as:

```
=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP([Cell in Column A],[Column B Range],1,FALSE)),"FALSE","TRUE")
```

This formula will return true when a matching value is found in column B.
Then simply apply the same rule again for column C.

Apply this rule to the entire range of your column A cells, and set the conditional formatting to return bold and red when true.

Good luck!

Example with ranges in one worksheet:
Formula as applied is

```
=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP($B3,$F:$F,1,FALSE)),"FALSE","TRUE")
```

[image: Example]